# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;)&#039;

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Error received in Drupal-6 Logs Entries

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 14 query: SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.uid AS node_uid, node.type AS node_type, node_revisions.format AS node_revisions_format, node_data_field_link_of_deal.field_link_of_deal_url AS node_data_field_link_of_deal_field_link_of_deal_url, node_data_field_link_of_deal.field_link_of_deal_title AS node_data_field_link_of_deal_field_link_of_deal_title, node_data_field_link_of_deal.field_link_of_deal_attributes AS node_data_field_link_of_deal_field_link_of_deal_attributes, node.vid AS node_vid FROM node node INNER JOIN term_node term_node ON node.vid = term_node.vid LEFT JOIN node_revisions node_revisions ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid LEFT JOIN content_type_popular_deal node_data_field_link_of_deal ON node.vid = node_data_field_link_of_deal.vid WHERE (node.type in ('popular_deal')) AND (term_node.tid = ) in /home/watzupdeal/www/customised_block/tag_cloud.php on line 20.

## MY CODE in tag_cloud.php

```
<?php
$city_id = $_COOKIE['city_id'];
$sql="  SELECT node.nid AS nid,
node.title AS node_title,
node.uid AS node_uid,
node.type AS node_type,
node_revisions.format AS node_revisions_format,
node_data_field_link_of_deal.field_link_of_deal_url AS        
node_data_field_link_of_deal_field_link_of_deal_url,
node_data_field_link_of_deal.field_link_of_deal_title AS      
node_data_field_link_of_deal_field_link_of_deal_title,
node_data_field_link_of_deal.field_link_of_deal_attributes AS     
node_data_field_link_of_deal_field_link_of_deal_attributes,
node.vid AS node_vid
FROM node node 
INNER JOIN term_node term_node ON node.vid = term_node.vid
LEFT JOIN node_revisions node_revisions ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid
LEFT JOIN content_type_popular_deal node_data_field_link_of_deal ON node.vid =     node_data_field_link_of_deal.vid
WHERE (node.type in ('popular_deal')) AND (term_node.tid = $city_id)
";

$result = db_query($sql);

?>
```

Comment: Look at the very last term in the query printed in the error message.

Comment: Just look at your `$city_id` it seems to become an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$city_id` is null or an empty string

```
... (term_node.tid = $city_id) ...
```

becomes this on the error message:

```
... (term_node.tid = ) ...
```

which makes it an sql syntax error. You should change it to this:

```
... (term_node.tid = '{$city_id}') ...
```